# Add class to custom form_for label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, form-for

How do I add a custom class to a form_for else statement?

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      .
      .
      .
      <%= f.label :name, 
        if @user.errors[:name].blank?
          'Name'
        else
          'Name ' + @user.errors[:name].to_sentence
        end
      %>
```

I've tried:

```
else
  'Name ' + @user.errors[:name].to_sentence, class: "some_class"
end
```

Also tried:

```
else
   'Name ' + @user.errors[:name].to_sentence, :class => "some_class"
end
```

but both generate unexpected errors.

I'm simply customizing the input label to display the validation error upon form submission and would like to change the text color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can do it in one line:

```
<%= f.label :name, (@user.errors[:name].blank? 'Name' : 'Name ' + @user.errors[:name].to_sentence) %>
```

Then:

```
<% if @user.errors[:name].blank? %>
  <%= f.label :name, 'Name' %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.label :name, 'Name ' + @user.errors[:name].to_sentence, :class => "some_class"  %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yeah, the if/else statement is in long form because I only want to add a class to one output. In this case, the output of the else statement should add a class to the f.label :name

Comment: Thanks zishe, any idea why my original method which is identical, doesn't work inside a single set of erb tags but yours does with tags on each line?

Comment: You can't use `<% ... %>` multiline. You should put them on each line.